# Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to lunch EC2 instance by using Terraform and I am getting the following error:

Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

I have applied AdministratorAccess policy to my IAM account so I guess there should not be IAM restriction issue.

Also I have MFA enabled for my account, but I am using STS token and the API calls are being accepted from Amazon so this should not be the issue as well.

The Terraform code that I am using is so simple:

```
provider "aws"{
    region="us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-00d4e9ff62bc40e03"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Please could you assist me as I tired so many things, but I didn't manage to solve the issue.
Thanks ahead in time!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct credentials? What happens if you output the returned values from the https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/caller_identity.html data source?

Comment: The credentials (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_ACCESS + TOKEN) are correct as I am seeing the same error into the CloudTrail

Answer (score 9):

Goto the user you have created for terraform from iamadmin then check the Policies .
I have found that "AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2" policy was Attached directly .
The description of the policy is :

Policy ARN
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2
Description
Denies access to certain actions, applied by the AWS team in the event that an IAM user's credentials have been compromised or exposed publicly. Do NOT remove this policy. Instead, please follow the instructions specified in the support case created for you regarding this event.

Check open issues in aws notification, It will show you **Risk IAM quarantine**

Your AWS Account may be compromised! We have opened a Support Case with more details. Please visit the AWS Support Center https://aws.amazon.com/support to review the case we've opened for you and take action immediately.

Answer (score 7):

You're got this error too, I fixed the same by recreating the user in AWS IAM console and then access/secret key. Why that happened is mistakenly I uploaded the tfvars file having access key and secret key to my github repo which was identified by AWS and then it restricted access over that particular IAM user. hats of to AWS for this micro level monitoring and security standard following.

Comment: It happened to me also revoked and create new keys but it works for eks cluster creating using terraform but same fails saying "Error: Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message". I tried manually creating with same user it works for rds but fails using terraform

Answer (score 3):

You can try to enable debugging when running the template so you can get a better idea in which permission piece is missing.

To enable logging in Windows:

```
SET TF_LOG=DEBUG
```

In Mac or other Linux:

```
export TF_LOG=DEBUG
```

Then run your Terraform command to see a detailed log, for example:

```
terraform apply
```

Comment: When I enable debug mode, there is no useful additional information only:

<root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: 
You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the STS service to decode the authorization token that you get with your response. It will state the exact action you don't have permission to perform.

For example, let's say you have this error:

```
Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: ajF9SwmLaGcBxg...
```

To decode the message, run:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message ajF9SwmLaGcBxg...
```

For more info: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch/

Answer (score 1):

Please go to your AWS console to see if you set the permissions boundary on this user. If yes, you can try to remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is:

- This is a new AWS account and the activation process haven't finished yet.
- Your AWS keys don't have enough permissions to launch EC2 instances.

Comment: The account is not a new one, it is already activated. I am able to lunch a new EC2 instance via the WEB console, but not trough Terraform. 
The AdministratorAccess policy is applied to the account. This buildin Policy provides full access to AWS services and resources so could it be some permission issue related ?

Comment: i am also experiencing this issue right. did you manage to fix it ? admin and ec2 permissions are added but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was trying to create a resource in a region forbidden by my organization's Service Control Policy. The user credentials were fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was accessing a wrong profile in my AWS config file.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIA........
aws_secret_access_key = JFV............

[org_1]
aws_access_key_id = AKIA............
aws_secret_access_key = EVg.................
```

This happened because I was trying to create a resource using credentials in the **default** profile I didn't have to create an EC2 instance.

This was however solved by changing the configuration to point to the profile **org_1** I intended to use

Therefore, If your AWS config file contains more than one profile, reference the correct profile in your terraform file. For example;

```
provider "aws" {
profile = "org_1"
region  = "us-west-..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct your IAM role
1 AdministratorAccess
2 AdministratorAccess-Amplify

if you pick second IAM role you have that error so change to first IAM role

Comment: Formatting would improve readability

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue. I manually set my aws access key and secret key in my windows machine by editing the environment variables. Not sure though why after setting up "aws configure" with keys and all, it did not update the env variables in the machine. The IAM user I have has AdministratorAccess. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

if you have uploaded your terraform file somewhere you will have to recreate user in IAM, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can check IAM user permissions. If this policy is attached, you can remove it directly.

AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the User Group for the user had 2 Permission Policies (AmazonEC2FullAccess and Force_MFA - custom policy to deny access if you did not MFA). So of course, using the access key method does not work because it does not use MFA!